# how to keep activity waiting until loading complete android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a splash screen Activity appear for 10 second while waiting this time the  Activity check if tables are created and all data are loaded form server 
if not it creates tables and load data to DB. every thing is OK but the problem is when loading data take more than 10 seconds  the Splash Activity is finished and start another Activity 
how i can keep splash activity wait until all data are loaded 
here is my code

```
if(! (checkTables()&&checkData())){
      progressDialog.show();
       fillSamples();
       fillExams();
       fillQuestions();
        fillSubQuestions();
        createProfile();
    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent studentAccess = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Samples.class);
            startActivity(studentAccess);
            finish();
        }
    },10000);
```

> i am using volley StringRequest and ImageRequest to download data and images from remote server

Comment: you can try something like [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52)

Comment: ammm i see my data correctly in other activities but the Splash Activity is start the Samples activity at the same time of lunching doInBackground method . i want to keep user in splash screen until loading is finish

Answer (score 3):

You can use AsyncTask ,it is better for network calls by creating this inner class

```
private class Operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do what ever operations you want 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
        }
        return "result";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("data", result);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

and execute the process using private method in splash activity like this

```
   new Operation().execute("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Network calls should be always called from not main thread.

What you do is that you are making your main thread sleep . **Never sleep you main thread.** Android will kill your app. Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for network calls (doInBackground) and onPostExectute() do all other things.

Comment: i will try this and reply you

Comment: ammm i see my data correctly in other activities but the Splash Activity is start the Samples activity at the same time of lunching doInBackground method . i want to keep user in splash screen until loading is finish